# Switch Case more efficient in C

Tags: c

So I have a program that handles data. When I enter a big data set, it works very slow. I think the problem is in the following code. Is there any way to make this part of the code more efficient?

I haven't got any results when trying to modify it myself.

```
while ((charCount = readline(fp, line)) >= 0) {
        if (lineCount == 0 || charCount == 0) {
            lineCount++;
            continue;
        }

        tokenCount = 0;
        token = strtok(line, ";");
        while (token) {
            switch (tokenCount) {

                case 0:
                    sprintf(name,"%s", token);
                break;

                case 1:
                    sscanf(token,"%" SCNd64, &epochTime);
                break;

                case 2:
                    sscanf(token,"%d", &day);
                break;

                case 3:
                    sscanf(token,"%d", &month);
                break;

                case 4:
                    sscanf(token,"%d", &year);
                break;

                case 5:
                    sscanf(token,"%d", &hour);
                break;

                case 6:
                    sscanf(token,"%d", &minute);
                break;

                case 7:
                    sscanf(token,"%d", &amount);
                break;

                default:
                    printf("Luku epäonnistui.\n");
                break;
            }

            tokenCount++;
            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        }
```

This code has been taken from middle of my program. So it might look a bit funny. Tried to compile with -O2, doesn't change.

```
if ((name = (char *)malloc(MAX_NAME_LEN)) == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to reserve memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((line = (char *)malloc(LINE_BUFFER_SIZE)) == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to reserve memory\n");
        free(name);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Five the filename: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    printf("Reading file '%s'\n", fileName);

    if ((fp = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to read file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: profile your code first. I highly doubt the switch is the cause

Comment: In the context of the `while` loop, `charCount` cannot be zero, so `if (lineCount == 0 || charCount == 0)` doesn't seem to make any sense.  I agree with @drum.

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Is there a simple instructions on profiling? Don't really understand it.

Comment: `sprintf(name,"%s", token);` could be replaced with `strcpy(name, token);`  But I doubt that's your performance issue.

Comment: Yes, it does compile without any problems

Comment: Oh nevermind, I googled what SCNd64 does.

Comment: Did you compile with `-O2` to optimize your code?  Does that speed anything up?

Comment: I did try, it doesn't speed up.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the `scanf` family of functions are incredibly slow.

They need to parse and handle a very wide set of format strings, so they are not a fast way to read data.

It looks like you're reading rows of data that is well-formatted tokens separated by `';'`, so rather than using `scanf`, after you parse the string with `strtok`, use functions like `atoi` or `strtol` to extract numbers much much faster.

```
while ((charCount = readline(fp, line)) >= 0) {
        if (lineCount == 0 || charCount == 0) {
            lineCount++;
            continue;
        }

        tokenCount = 0;
        token = strtok(line, ";");
        while (token) {
            switch (tokenCount) {

                case 0:
                    strcpy(name, token); //sprintf(name,"%s", token);
                break;

                case 1:
                    sscanf(token,"%" SCNd64, &epochTime);
                break;

                case 2:
                    day = strtol(token,NULL,10);
                break;

                case 3:
                    month = strtol(token,NULL,10);
                break;

                case 4:
                    year = strtol(token,NULL,10);
                break;

                case 5:
                    //DITTO: // sscanf(token,"%d", &hour);
                break;

                case 6:
                    //DITTO // sscanf(token,"%d", &minute);
                break;

                case 7:
                    //DITTO // sscanf(token,"%d", &amount);
                break;

                default:
                    printf("Luku epäonnistui.\n");
                break;
            }

            tokenCount++;
            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm using this to handle 10 000lines of data (mainly numbers). How would the usage from sscanf to strchr be possible in this occasion?

Comment: Did you try benchmarking this? I did a rough benchmark using three solutions, all of them opencoded rather than using a switch statement (although it makes very little difference). The benchmark reads a 10,000-line input file 100 times, for a total of a million lines; average line length is approximately 60.3 bytes, so the test is a tad more than 60MB. The process writes output records to `/dev/null`; writing to a real file dominates the execution time (which is a clue about how unimportant the benchmark is, I think)...

Comment: The pure sscanf solution, which uses a single call to sscanf with a total of nine conversions (plus a scattering of semicolons) takes 0.50-0.53 seconds on my laptop. Your `strtok` solution (or something similar to it) uses 0.38-0.40 seconds. A solution I wrote which actually uses the `end` argument returned by `strtol` comes in at 0.17-0.19 seconds, so it's the clear winner. But that's just one measure, and possibly not an important one. By far the simplest code is the one using `sscanf`.

Comment: FWIW, I used a 96-byte name field which is zero filled either with `memset` or `strncpy`, depending on the benchmark (`memset` for `sscanf`). I needed to do that so that the output would be comparable between runs. The additional overhead is minor, but it might be measurable.

Comment: Update: I changed your call to `sscanf` for the `int64_t` field to a call to `strtoll`. That cut down the run time significantly, to 0.26-0.28 seconds. So that's some kind of confirmation of your claim that `sscanf` is slow, although it seems like a single call with multiple conversions is not as much slower as might be expected from that result.